A solution for a first order ODE
I want to solve the following ODE
$$
y'=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}
$$
My attempt: Set $x=r(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. The right hand side is
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}=\frac{r(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}
$$
What is the left-hand side? Is there a simple method (such as using an integration factor)?

What you mean by "closed-form"  ? it may have a solution as an implicit  equation.

Why is $r$ a function of $\theta $?

Using the transformation $U(x)=\frac{1}{x+y(x)}$, the equation can be transformed to an Abel equation of the first kind:
$$U'=-U-(1-2x)U^2-2x^2U^3$$
This equation does not seem to be one of the simple, solvable Abel equation cases (for example, it can be written as a Chini equation but its Chini invariant seems to be non-constant).  However in a relatively recent paper the authors have expressed the solution to the most general Abel equation of the first kind in parametric form, given in equations $(2.28), (2.29)$ in the paper. The parametric form depends on the reduction of the above Abel equation to its normal form
$$X'=X^3+F(\xi)$$
which can be achieved by the transformations
$$\xi=\int dx f_3E^2\\X=\left(U+\frac{f_2}{3f_3}\right)E^{-1}\\E=\exp\left(\int dx \left[f_1-\frac{f_2^2}{3f_3}\right]\right)$$
For this Abel equation $f_1=-1,\, f_2=2x-1,\, f_3=-2x^2,\, E=x^{2/3}\exp(-\frac{5x}{3}+\frac{1}{6x})\,$. Also the form of $F$ is implicitly given by
$$F(\xi)=(f_3(x) E^3(x))^{-1}\left[f_3(x) E^2(x)\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)+\frac{1}{6x^2}-\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{1}{54}\frac{(2x-1)^3}{x^4}\right]\Bigg|_{x=x(\xi)}$$
According to the authors, once reduced to this form, the general solution can be written as
$$\left(\frac{2X}{G}-\frac{Y_{\nu}(G)}{Y_{\nu-1}(G)-Y_{\nu+1}(G)}\right)\left(\frac{2X}{G}+\frac{J_{\nu}(G)}{J_{\nu-1}(G)-J_{\nu+1}(G)}+\frac{Y_{\nu}(G)}{Y_{\nu-1}(G)-Y_{\nu+1}(G)}\right)=f\left(\frac{J_{\nu}(G)}{J_{\nu-1}(G)-J_{\nu+1}(G)}-\frac{Y_{\nu}(G)}{Y_{\nu-1}(G)-Y_{\nu+1}(G)}\right)$$
$$G^2(\xi)=\nu-\frac{f}{C^2\Omega}~~ ,~~ \Omega(\xi)=f^3+X^3+fX^2~~ ,~~ f=F^{1/3}$$
In this expression, the integration constant $C$ and the order of the Bessel functions $\nu$ can be chosen freely.
